# Web3py: how to track if the token listed on pancakeswap and can be trade(swap)?

Tags: web3.py, bsc, pancakeswap, bscscan

I used python web3py to trade pancakeswap via BSC(Binance smart chain). It is working.
But i want to track when one token is listed on pancakeswap and can be trade.
I has tried to use contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter on pancakeswap Factory. But although Pair has been created, token may not be available for swap yet.
Any body can hepl me! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Liquidity should be added before buying of the token can occur